# Can't get Scala support in Intellij-IDEA working (though I've done this a dozen times before)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have several machines. I just bought a new MacBook and installed Scala, set and then IntelliJ IDE. Nothing I do will make it correctly create or import a Scala project. I get message some times that the Scala library is not configured. Sometimes I can add the Scala Framework manually and sometimes Scala isn't an option in Add Framework. I have reinstalled SBT Scala, the Intellij Scala plugin and even IDEA. Every other machine is fine and I never had any problems - I'm going to have to give-up on Intellij at this point and use Eclipse (a cheaper option than sticking with the old laptop). I have different settings and options than the other machines as I'm on a slightly newer (2018.2) IDEA build but other than that I'm at a loss.

Anyone hit this before? What stupid thing have I done wrong?

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors. Report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with the logs/sample project attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get that is that there are certain combinations of SBT and IntelliJ that just don't work well together.  Go to *project/build.properties* in your project and change your SBT version from to something like `1.1.1` (That one works well for me) and experiment. I know it is frustrating.  Also be sure that IntelliJ and Scala plugins are upgraded.

Comment: Well that does seem to work for me but I still need to manually add the Scala Framework rather than it doing it automatically when I select a Scala SBT project. Clearly there isn't much testing that goes on at Intellij as this is using the bundled SBT rather than an external one...